# Where are my Hard Drives/Local Disks on the COMPUTER/System Folder in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive

Being first to try Ubuntu.

But Where are my Hard Drives/Local Disks on the COMPUTER/System Folder in Ubuntu 12.04?!

Before installing 12.04 i had tried the Ubuntu 10.10 Version Live and it was perfect in showing my Local Disks. But it couldn't recognize my GTX 470 Graphics driver so i thought of trying the recent version i.e 12.04. Fortunately it solved the Graphics driver thing but now i am stuck with finding My Local Disks on 12.04.
I am sorry if this is a silly question, but i know nothing of Ubuntu at the moment.

Regards,

Comment: Which option did you select when you installed ubuntu? did you select "Do something else" and then manually assign a partition or did you select "Install alongside windows" or did you select "Erase everything and install"? if it was the 3rd option,m sorry to tell you that you formatted the complete hard disk and lost everything....

Comment: Do you mean different partitions of same drive or other internal hard drive. Or rather both if present. Also post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: You mean the drives icons on the desktop?

Answer (score 4):

If the disk are mounted, and you are just looking to where they are mounted, you can type:

```
mount
```

That will show you which device is mounted where.
If you want to see what drives are physically attached to your machine, but might not be mounted:

```
ls -al /dev | grep sd
```

The sd[abc...] files are your hdd's.

Answer (score 0):

All *nix operting systems hide the physical disks, and have a single directory tree starting at `/`.

The various disks and partitions are mounted on mount points under `/`, and in complex systems there can be many separate ones (`/home` is a typical example). I have `/tmp` on a separate disk. `/boot` is often a separate partition.

The default install will probably have created two partitions, one for swap, and one for `/`.

As was said, the `mount` command will display what is currently mounted. `/etc/fstab` contains the list of mounts done automatically at boot-up.

Removable devices are usually auto-detected by a hotplug mechanism, and auto-mounted--typically under `/media` using their volume names.